# Select certificate to add web reference for web service

Tags: web-services, https, wsdl, ssl-certificate, truststore

I am trying to add a **web reference** for a web service but it prompts me to **select a certificate**. The **cert is installed in my trust store** and uploaded on the web services's server. But when i request the wsdl (in browser/uddi) i dont see my cert in the select cert pop up. Note that my **cert does not have any private key** and its a **.cer** format. I have already tried importing the certificate in web browser/trust store but no luck. 
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: it seems the cert with no private key was the issue. I created another .pfx cert and imported it, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey having same problem here, at the end I have downloaded the wsdl file and create the reference from there.